# Как отправить данные с формы на почтовый ящик с помощью Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, форма

Начинаю осваивать vue.js и столкнулся с проблемой, как отправить данные с формы на email.

Форма выглядит вот так:

```
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" id="form">

                <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
                <input type="hidden" id="project_name" name="project_name" value="Проект">
                <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" id="admin_email" value="info@mail.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" id="form_subject" value="Заявка с сайта">
                <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

                <input required placeholder="Введите E-mail" type="email" id="email" name="email">
                <textarea required placeholder="Введите сообщение" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" placeholder="Отправить">
            </form>
```

Вот непосредственно сам код Vue.js. насколько я понял axios данные изначально отправлzет в JSON, возможно проблема в этом.

```
methods: {
            onSubmit() {
                const params = new URLSearchParams();
                params.append('email', this.email);
                params.append('message', this.message);
                params.append('project_name', this.project_name);
                params.append('admin_email', this.email);
                params.append('form_subject', this.form_subject);

                axios.post(
                        "/mail.php",
                        params, {
                            headers: {
                                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                            }
                        }

                    ).then(function(responce) {
                        console.log('SUCCESS!!');
                    })
                    .catch(function() {
                        console.log('FAILURE!!');
                    });
            },
        },
```

А вот сам код обработчика формы:

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

  $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
  $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
  $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
      $message .= "
      " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
      </tr>
      ";
    }
  }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

  $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
  $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
  $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

  foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
      $message .= "
      " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
      </tr>
      ";
    }
  }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
  return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

После нажатия кнопки "отправить" в консоль лог SUCCESS!! высвечивается. Но на сервере в логах вот это:
: Undefined variable: message in ../mail.php on line 18,
Словно не может подцепить значение из textarea

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Используйте `$_REQUEST`, не плодите проверки на тип запроса, либо используйте только `$_POST` *(это не решение вопроса)*

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что Вы не можете добавлять в конец переменной какие-либо значения, когда она не была определена. Т.е. в первом цикле Вы делаете `$message .= '...'`, но где переменная определена до этого? Нельзя тому что не существует, добавить строку.
определите перед первым циклом `$message = '';` и будет счастье!